# How do I find out how much space I have left on SkyDrive?

Tags: onedrive

I'm not talking about Synced Folders, I'm talking about the "other" space.

With the old layout it was easy, it was shown on the right, but with the new layout I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: Odd, I could not find this either. I just know I'm no where near 5GB, let alone 25GB.  I've gotta start thinking up of stuff to take up space. . .

Comment: Couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 1):

This has probably changed in the last year, but it is now visible in the lower left corner or you can go to the [Manage Storage](https://skydrive.live.com/options/ManageStorage) option to view usage and buy more if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 you can go to:

Settings > Change PC Settings > Skydrive

You will see how much total space you have allocated and what is used.

Answer (score 1):

In Win 10, I right-click the OneDrive icon in the notifications area. From among the offered choices that come up, I choose the "settings". In the box that comes up in settings you should see tabs across the top; select the tab labeled "account". There you should see a statement of how much of your allotted storage is used out of the total, e.g. "3.4 GB of 205 GB cloud storage used".

Answer (score 0):

In my Surface 2, I go to *Settings*, then select *Change your PC settings*, then you will see the option *SkyDrive*, then select **File storage**. The space available will be displayed there.